# External Tangents of Circles.

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry

If we have three circles C1 C2 C3. Consider the intersection between the external tangents of each pair of circles . Show that the three points of the intersections are collinear.

Is this a well known theorem on its own?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio That could be an answer...

Answer (score 2):

It is known as [Monge's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monge%27s_theorem). On the wikipedia page you can also find different proofs.